# Floor Joists And Notched On Sill Plate

Tags: framing, joists

I have mastered many things in life, but carpentry is not one. I need to replace some flooring, and floor joist, that rotted from water damage, and it does not look like how i have seen others.

The joist seems to be notched, sitting on the sill plate, in fact the whole flooring looks odd. I have the main beam, and the joists are nailed to each other, and rest above the beam. Normally what i see are hangers, attached to the support beam, and then attached to a ledger board (i think that is what it is called), but mine seems to be notched and no hangers.

Is this normal? The house was built in 1985, not sure if that matters.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Seems like photos are in order. There aren't usually ledgers in 1980s floor framing, or hangers, for that matter. Please use the button in the editor toolbar and follow the instructions to include clear, well-lit photos showing us some context.

Comment: Will do, but will be a couple of days, i need to finish removing the floor to get good photos.

Comment: Then you may as well delete this and post a full question when you can. Otherwise post what you can see now so we have something to talk about.

Comment: Structurally, you don’t need the full depth of the joist at the bearing point (wall). What is the size of the joists? Spacing? Span? Size of notch?

Comment: Once i got to the point of seeing the whole issue, what i was seeing was not a notch, it was just the was the joist sank into the sill plate. I have a big mess to sort out, since i need to replace 4 floor joists (2x10x12'), sill plate and rim joist, on two sides, the damage is in a corner. It is now just a matter of the repair order.